# Invalid object name '#volume'

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am getting the following message

> Invalid object name #Volume

on alternate run of a stored procedure that has the following code. If the twoBD column value is <48 then it will show Met in Column TAT.And in column twoBD values are comes like below

00:20,

00:40

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[gsktat]
(     
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime

)
AS
BEGIN

  SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

    create table #volume (Sdate datetime,edate datetime ,vstatus varchar(50)
                            ,twoBD varchar(50),TAT varchar(50),ageing int)

    insert into #volume(Sdate,edate,vstatus,twoBD)
        (select [Start date],[End date],[Status],dbo.[GetWorkingMinss]([Start date],[End date],'ss') from GSK)
    Declare @claimid int
    set @claimid = '48'
    If Exists (Select * from #volume where 
        (SELECT 
         RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),( ((cast(STR(Floor(REPLACE(twoBD,':','.')),8,0)as int)*60+CAST(Right(00.45,2) as int)))%3600)/60),2) 
         +':' 
         + RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ((cast(STR(Floor(REPLACE(twoBD,':','.')),8,0)as int)*60+CAST(Right(00.45,2) as int)))%60),2) AS [ TAT] 
         )<= @claimid)
    begin
        insert into #volume(TAT)values('Met')
    end
    else
    begin
        insert into #volume(TAT)values('Not Met')
        select * from #volume
    end                         

end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to you a temporary table named #volume you have to create it first. The must be done each time you use it because it is temporary.

Since you don't show the rest of your code, there is no way to tell you how to fix it.

ADDED you posted proc code now

I don't actually see a problem in your code, can't be sure there is no problem with tables, your GetWorkingMins() etc. but don't see how those would cause the missing #volume message.

But I do see something odd. You say the error message is "Invalid object name #Volume" but I am pretty sure that SQL server does not change  **#volume** into **#Volume** in an error message -- just tried it locally (2005) and it did not. Makes me wonder if you don't have another version of this proc that you are actually calling -- the sql catalog can be confused too, so it may not be your code causing the problem, though this is a rare problem. Add a print or another method to the top of your proc to make sure what you calling is the same as what you think you are calling.

Another possibility is that the message can be coming from an inner stored proc that is causing the weirdness. Try changing the #volume to #myvolume in gskstat() and see if the error message changes

Having created #volume at the top of your proc is a good thing for debugging this. The lifetime is pretty well defined in the case, #volume will go away when the proc ends. Even if the calling proc or client connection also create #volume gskstat() should not have any problems because of it (sql will create a 2nd #volume table (with a different hidden tablename suffix)